# cordova-plugin-file-transfer and file open

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I implemented a downloader file with this code in my app ionic cordova:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-transfer/ngx';


constructor(
        private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions, 
        private file: File,
        //private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser,
        private transfer: FileTransfer
    ) {
    }


download(fileId:string) {

    const authInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(environment.authInfoKey));

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    const url = `rest api`;
    fileTransfer.download(
        url, 
        this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'file.pdf',false,{
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${authInfo.access_token}`
            }
        }).then((entry) => {
            console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());


            ...
            ...

            )

    }, (error) => {
      // handle error
      console.info('error');
    });
}
```

after this file stored in my folder, I can see with the file inspector in my device.

Now I would this, without other plugin (if possibile)

[image]

Comment: You would what?? Please always re-read your question before posting.

Comment: the attached image is the example of what I would like to achieve, right now I'm trying cordova-plugin-file-opener2, and that's exactly what I want, but the project seems abandoned and I didn't want to use it

Comment: if you only have PDF format you can also use: 
https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer